# How to su into another user and run commands with subsequent interactive shell

Tags: sudo, su

My goal is to su into user2, run commands that reference user1's environment, and also initiate an interactive shell as user2. I'm trying to create a function that allows me to keep forwarding X after su'ing to another user.

The following command works as intended, except that bash becomes extremely buggy:

```
sudo su - user2 -c "export DISPLAY=$orig_display; xauth add $orig_xconfig ; bash"
```

The $orig_display and $orig_xconfig arguments are predefined arguments that exist in user1's environment.

In essence, I'd like to combine the -c and -l flags for su but they seem to be mutually exclusive.

Comment: Note `su into another user and run commands with subsequent interactive shell` is broader than `keep forwarding X after su'ing to another user`. My answer solves (or at least tries to solve) the latter but it doesn't solve the former in general. If it's enough, the title should be changed (compare [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)). If you really need to run *arbitrary* commands before an interactive shell, please state this clearly ([edit]); then leave a comment under my answer, I will probably adjust it to the more general problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you call "extreme bugginess" is mainly because of what `man 1 su` says about `-c`:

> The executed command will have no controlling terminal.

---

Do it in two steps.

1. Set the X authority file for user2:

   ```
   sudo -u user2 xauth add $orig_xconfig
   # or
   # sudo su user2 -c "xauth add $orig_xconfig"
   ```
2. Run a shell. Note `su -` preserves `$DISPLAY`; `sudo -i` should also preserve `$DISPLAY`. Therefore:

   ```
   DISPLAY="$orig_display" sudo -i su -s /bin/bash - user2
   ```

   Your original code tried to run `bash` regardless of user2's default shell, so I used `-s /bin/bash`. You may or may not want it.